# Show div tag when selecting an option | Angular1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show a div tag when selecting a specific option. I am developing this with Angular and Ionic 1. I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't find any answers that works for me, therefore I'm writing this. I want to display the second option (id number 2), but I can't get it to work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row row-white">
    <div class="col col-white">
<label>
    <select name="keys" ng-options="key.name for key in list" ng-change="myCtrl()" ng-model="testValue"  class="select-input" style="margin-left:0px;">
        <option ng-if="false"></option>
        <option ng-value=""></option>
        <option ng-value=""></option>
    </select>
</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divider20"></div>
<div class="row row-white" ng-show="result"> <!-- Won't display!! -->
    <div class="col col-white">
        <input type="number">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
    $scope.list = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Engångsnyckel"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Fleragångsnyckel"
}]

$scope.myCtrl = function() {
    if ($scope.testValue.id == "2") {
        $scope.result = true
    }
    else {
        $scope.result = false
    }
}
// Sets the first index as placeholder
$scope.testValue = $scope.list[0]
```

Sorry if this is a dumb and obvious question, but I'm getting desperate.

Comment: try using `if ($scope.testValue.id == 2) {
        $scope.result = true
    }` because your id is an integer not string

Comment: @XYZ I tried it. It didnt do the trick :(

Comment: I don't remember Angular 1 much but its something like this  `<option ngClick="!$scope.showDiv"></option>` and `<div ngShow="$scope.showDiv">`

Comment: @MartinNordström check if `<div class="row row-white" ng-show="result">` is inside the ng-controller

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32724/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help. You can directly use the data binding property without depending on any functions for the static conditions.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Id One"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "The Id Two"
}]
// Sets the first index as placeholder
$scope.testValue = $scope.list[0]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <div class="row row-white">
    <div class="col col-white">
<label>
    <select name="keys" ng-options="key.name for key in list" ng-model="testValue"  class="select-input" style="margin-left:0px;">
        <option ng-if="false"></option>
        <option ng-value=""></option>
        <option ng-value=""></option>
    </select>
</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divider20"></div>
<div class="row row-white" ng-show="testValue.id==2"> <!-- Won't display!! -->
    <div class="col col-white">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter the number here">
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison should be with a number

```
$scope.myCtrl = function() {
    if ($scope.testValue.id == 2) {
        $scope.result = true
    }
    else {
        $scope.result = false
    }
}
```

It's nice to use track by too in your

```
<select name="keys" ng-options="key as key.name for key in list track by key.id" ng-change="myCtrl()" ng-model="testValue"  class="select-input" style="margin-left:0px;">
</select>
```